# PHPMyAdmin put the most recent database

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I'm wondering if there is any better way than going through the tables one by one adding the columns missing when some fields/tables needs to be added because of the most recent changes in the app?

For example, I'm working at the localhost and when I finish doing the new version of my app, I will put all the files into my FTP and, sometimes, I have done, in my local database, changes and so it means that I also need to update my database at my server.

There's any better way to add/edit the columns/tables without changing the info? Some of the columns are also deleted, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hopefully you've thought your database design through so that making changes to the structure is a rare occurrence. If you're making regular changes to the number of columns or adding tables, it's likely a sign that you haven't normalized your database structure sufficiently.

Anyway, I'd script it as an SQL file that you deploy (which you can then run through phpMyAdmin or the command line or any other means you prefer to execute SQL queries). This has the added advantage of being something you can easily duplicate across your development and production databases, send to customers, and if you wish store in version control so you know when exactly you made the changes to the database.

This way, you'll end up with an SQL file that has a couple of statements like

```
ALTER TABLE `foo` ADD `new` INT NOT NULL ;
```

or something similar.

As for how you'd make the file, probably the easiest way is just copying and pasting the generated SQL statement from phpMyAdmin after modifying the table -- the SQL code used to make the change is shown near the top of the screen on the next page. You can copy and paste that to a new text file to create your SQL file. You may wish to add the first line

```
use `baz`;
```

using your database name instead of "baz". That way you don't have to specify on import which database the changes are meant for.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Unfortunately its my boss problem. I make a project after a while he remembers that he wants to add 10 more features..well, I've to add columns :\

Thank you.